# Неправильная генерация чисел C++

Tags: c

Нужно реализовать генерацию рандомных чисел с помощью линейного конгуретного метода, множитель(a) = 1103515245, прирост(c) = 12345, модуль(m).
Вот код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <random>


int main() 
{
  unsigned int arr[10000], count[100] = { 0 }, a = 1103515245, c = 12345;
  unsigned long long m = pow(2, 31);
  double arr1[100] = { 0 }, stat[100] = { 0 }, M = 0, d = 0;
  arr[0] = time(0);

  for (int i = 1; i < 10000; i++)
  {
    arr[i] = (a * arr[i - 1]+c) % m;
    arr[i - 1] %= 100;
    count[arr[i - 1]]++;
  }
  arr[999] %= 100;
  printf(" Генерація випадкових чисел:\n");
  for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
  {
    printf("\n %d= %d", i, count[i]);
  }
  printf("Статистична ймовірність випадкових чисел:\n");
  int i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < 100; i++);
  {
    stat[i] = count[i] / 10000;
    M += stat[i] * i;
  }
  printf("\n %d= %f", i, stat[i]);

  printf("Частота інтервалів випадкових чисел:\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  {
    d += pow((i - M), 2) * stat[i];
  }
  printf("Дисперсія= %f", d);
  printf("Відхилення випадкових чисел= %f", pow(d,1/2.));

  return 0;
}
```

P.S. сгенерированые числа выходят за диапазон (0-100)

Comment: `i < 10000;` — так какое число последнее? Точно 999-е? `arr[999] %= 100;`?

Comment: там до числа 10000, опечатался, но оно всё равно не правильно генерирует

Comment: В чем это проявляется? Как вы это видите? То, что у вас поганое  распределение - это немного другое... Это как минимум неудачное `m` и вообще не использованное `c`.

Comment: среднее не очень правильно считаете `M += stat[i] + i;` может быть так : `M += stat[i] * i;` ?

Comment: Добавил c, и изменил M, но результата не дало, проблема именно в генерации

Comment: Еще раз и медленно — как, например, мне увидеть, что генерируются значения, превышающие 100? Вас же это волнует, а не то, что генерация написана из рук вон плохо (Ну вот, например, в какой диапазон вписываются значения `a*arr[i - 1]`? А какой тип при вычислении вы используете?)? Убедите меня, что там у вас после `%100` остаются значения, превышающие 100...